# Doctrine Raw SQL not calling custom function

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm having an issue calling an custom defined function in my database from Doctrine when using the Raw SQL.

Here is an example SQL Query that is being run

```
 SELECT unicodeDecoder(answer) from answers;
```

`unicodeDecoder` is a custom defined function in my database and runs perfectly fine when I run the SQL statement directly on the database.

However when I run the query using raw sql, as follows:

```
$sql = "SELECT unicodeDecoder(answer) from answers";
$stmt = $this->getEntitityManager()->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION unicodeDecoder does not exist
```

Do I need to create a custom ORM mapping when using custom functions or could this be some form of caching issue?

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: check you are using the right user (check the privileges)

Comment: Hi Matteo, I'm definately using the right user as all other queries are working without issue. Thanks though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If found the issue. Thank you to @alex-blex for giving me a point of somewhere to start looking.

My database has a `.` in the name: `cms.app.com`

The issue was caused by the `.`

When Doctrine tries to access the method it automatically appends the database name to the beginning.

When I attempted to add the `cms.app.com` to the beginning (as suggested by @alex-blex) it created the following method call (which is the wrong syntax)

```
cms.app.com.unicodeDecoder()
```

I attempted the following

`cms.app.com`.unicodeDecoder but this still resolved to

```
cms.app.com.unicodeDecoder()
```

I removed the `.` from the database name and it now works as expected.

**Important Note**: Do not use `.` in your database name as Doctorine doesn't resolve the name correctly as the ` symbol get stripped out.

Answer (score 2):

Try to prefix the function with database name:

```
$sql = "SELECT my_db.unicodeDecoder(answer) from answers";
```

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately. It just complains with the same error, however the method is now prefixed with the database name in the error.